# Using a taglet with Javadoc in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, javadoc, taglet

I've written a custom taglet, compiled it and am now trying to use it but keep getting a ClassNotFoundException when I try to run it with javadoc:

`javadoc: error - Error - Exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException thrown while trying to register Taglet proj2.javadoc.CustomTaglet...`

In netbeans under the documentation I've specified the following arguments:

`-taglet proj2.javadoc.CustomTaglet -tagletpath c:\`

I've put the class file in C:\ (for now at least) and I've triple checked the class name but I'm still getting the exception. Is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put class files in a path matching their package name. So netbeans/javadoc is looking for your CustomTaglet.class in c:\proj2\javadoc

Comment: Dah, silly mistake - you're dead right, I thought I'd tried this but clearly missed it! Much appreciated.