# LaTeX mathematics in javadoc generated by Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, javadoc, netbeans-7, taglet

Is there a way how to include LaTeX formulas in javadoc generated by Netbeans? I found following taglet: http://users.informatik.uni-halle.de/~grau/LaTeXlet/index.html

It requires modifying javadocs arguments...

```
-taglet latexlet.InlineBlockLaTeXlet -taglet latexlet.BlockLaTeXlet -taglet latexlet.InlineLaTeXlet -tagletpath path/to/the/jar/LaTeXlet.jar
```

how can I do that?

Comment: seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5236513/using-a-taglet-with-javadoc-in-netbeans

Comment: yes, but I don't know where should I specify arguments for javadoc. is it in project properties?